getting wrong data when using laravel api with xampp
I am making two projects. 1st project offer functionality and 2nd one uses them.
I have defined api route in 1st as
Route::get('css', function(){
    return env('APP_NAME');
});

When i trigger this route it shows db1. But when i trigger this api route from 2nd project as
Route::get('db', function () {
    return file_get_contents('http://mantisui.test/api/css');
});

It shows db2 instead of db1. I am doing this in xampp making two separate folders with different port and virtual hosts.

I do not know what you are trying to achieve but instead of returning data in your .env file, why not return the value from the function? likely your second app is named db2 in the APP_NAME

i want to use api from 1st app, but i was getting error. so, i checked which database it uses in api then it uses 2nd project database instead of 1st. Assume it like creating an api route to get databse name and use it in 2nd project

it is a bad design to expose variables in the .env files to another application, why not fetch the data and expose the data via api
